# spring config server git ssh unknownhostkey

Tags: spring, ssh

I deployed Spring cloud config server to connect to git repository over ssh.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://git@stash.ops.domain.com:2022/ccare/cm-config-data.git
          searchPaths: [preferences, orders]
```

I have added the ssh keys(id_rsa.pub) to Git stash. 
I have also added /.ssh/config file with StrictHostKeyChecking no option.
But I still keep getting this error when I access the config server.

```
[nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clone or checkout repository] with root cause
```

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: stash.ops.domain.com. RSA key fingerprint is 39:89:4b:aa:79:fc:01:9f:46:48:5b:b9:6f:17:af:d5
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:786)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1115)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:265)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:237)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem. My proposed solution (which I used) is a hack but worked for me. Just `ssh` that server

```
ssh stash.ops.domain.com
```

You will get the following prompt:

```
The authenticity of host 'stash.ops.domain.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is <fingerprint>
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If you say `yes` then `stash.ops.domain.com` will be added to the `known_hosts`.
After it has been added you will no longer get that error.

Comment: This will not work if the server's pubkey is not in ssh-rsa format. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1027613/differing-ssh-known-hosts-formats